# Hadoop - Failure Recovery For Reduce Only

Tags: hadoop

I have a Hadoop job running which has finished the map part for for 4 days, and now it seems to get suspended at the stage of reduce (reducer is done for 30%)

I really hope to have a way to only re-process the reduce part if at all possible without having to re-process the long-run map part, Any suggestions?
Something probably gets it worse that I only have one reducer.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop will only restart the Reduce step in your case.

However, if your job fails, you can't just skip the map step.
In this case you should probably split the two stages into seperate jobs, especially if your mapper is computational intensive.